# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] creates extra slash at end

Tags: php

When I use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in my localhost it outputs: `C:/apache2.2/htdocs`.

However when I use it on my server it outputs: `/var/www/`

I can't use `stripslashes()` since it removes all slashes even from beginning. Any suggestion how to counter this? I don't mind if the outputs has slash or none at end. But I just want it to be the same for both files. So I don't keep changing paths by adding or removing slashes.

Btw I cannot change anything on my server. However I can change my local to match the server but don't know how.

Comment: please dont use images, when you could copy and paste

Comment: @Dagon they weren't images, OP just wrapped them in `<kbd>`

Comment: ahh it just killed my brain and made me move on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/')
```

to normalise the string. See http://php.net/manual/function.rtrim.php.

I strongly recommend **never** relying on DOCUMENT_ROOT as it is an external dependency. Instead, use the magic constants `__DIR__` and `__FILE__` to refer to paths relative to your scripts. For example...

```
$someDirRelativeToThisFile = __DIR__ . '/some-dir'; // PHP >= 5.3.0
$someDirRelativeToThisFile = dirname(__FILE__) . '/some-dir'; // PHP < 5.3.0
```

See http://php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: thanks. Didn't know there's a function that trims at end only. 

I tried using magic constants at first. But my server doesn't allow that. Don't know why. But whenever I use magic constant there. It outputs it literally like: __DIR__/fileshere.

Comment: @aozora What version of PHP? You may need to use `dirname(__FILE__)` in place of `__DIR__` if < 5.3.0

Comment: _“But whenever I use magic constant there. It outputs it literally like: __DIR__/fileshere”_ – then you most likely used it inside a string variable, where of course it will be treated as literal text.

Comment: PHP Version 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.25 quite an old server. This is how I use it `$upOne = realpath(__DIR__ . '/..');
$path = $upOne . '/includes/functions.php';`

Comment: @aozora there you go. `__DIR__` doesn't exist in PHP 5.2.4. Use `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))` instead

Comment: @CBroe PHP would be triggering an undefined constant notice and then defaulting to the string `"__DIR__"`. OP probably has `E_NOTICE` level errors hidden

Comment: @Phil: That’s not what I meant. Using `"__DIR__/foo"` or `'__DIR__/foo'` would get you the literal output `__DIR__/foo` (as aozora mentioned), and it doesn’t trigger a notice of course.

Comment: @CBroe yes, but so would `__DIR__ . '/foo'` if `__DIR__` wasn't defined (as is the case in OP's PHP version). As indicated in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31258976/serverdocument-root-creates-extra-slash-at-end/31259226?noredirect=1#comment50514749_31259226), OP isn't using it in a string literal.

Comment: Well that comment (and clarification about the PHP version used) came only later.